# Windows mobile 10 emulator

Tags: windows

I have installed Windows mobile 10 emulator on windows 8.1 machine.
I have enabled Hyper-V and created virtual machine for the emulator also.
But while launching the emulator I am getting this error [emulator wasnt able to set VHD ib the vitual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CptrH.png)
I am running the XDE file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0 to launch Emulator.

Can anyone help me out to salve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is strongy recommended that you upgrade to Windows 10 ASAP. In the meantime, check if your machine has the minimum recommended installed RAM (4G). Remember that usage is from command line

```
xde.exe /name virtualMachineName
```

To check names of created VM, open a powershell command window and type:

```
get-VM
```

This command will display a list, where the first column is the name of the corresponding VM. Copy the VM name to the clipboard (selecting with the mouse, then pressing ENTER). Close PowerShell window. 
Suppose that the name is "Emulator WVGA 512MB.JohnPaul", then in your CMD window, you must type:

```
xde.exe /name "Emulator WVGA 512MB.JohnPaul"
```

The emulator will launch. Hope this help.